# Prove that $(X,d)$ is complete iff every $(X_n,d_n) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ is complete.

Tags: metric-spaces

> Prove that $(X,d)$ is complete iff every $(X_n,d_n) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ is complete.

Let $(X_n, d_n) \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a family of metric spaces. Define

$$
X = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : x_j \in X_j\}
$$

Furthermore let $(\gamma_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset (0, \infty)$ be a sequence s.t $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n < \infty$. Let $x,y \in X$ where $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $y = (y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and define

$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \gamma_n \frac{d_n(x_n,y_n)}{1 + d_n(x_n,y_n)}
$$
where $d(x,y)$ is a metric on $X$.

I need a hint on how to get started on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

$(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(X,d)\implies d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon \forall n,m\ge p$

$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n\dfrac{d_n(x_m,x_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,x_m)}
<\epsilon$

$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty }\gamma _n\dfrac{d_n(x_m,x_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,x_m)}
=0$
(If  the series $\sum a_n$converges then $\lim a_n=0$)

Hence $\gamma _n\dfrac{d_n(x_m,x_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,x_m)}
<\epsilon$

Since $\gamma_n$ is convergent so $\dfrac{d_n(x_m,x_n)}{1+d_n(x_n,x_m)}
<\epsilon$

Now the function $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing so $d_n(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon$

Can you take it now?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the part "$\gamma_n $ is convergent so..."?

Comment: The choice of $m$ makes it all confusing for me since, $d$ is defined to be a sum over $n$

Comment: Since the series $\sum \gamma_n$ is convergent so $\lim \gamma_n=0$ and hence $\gamma_n$ is bounded so whenever the product of $\gamma_n $ and that $\dfrac{d_n}{1+d_n}<\epsilon \implies \dfrac{d_n}{1+d_n}<\epsilon$

Comment: you will have to fill up the rest

Comment: I dont see it, looking at $0.1 \cdot 10 < 2 \not \Rightarrow 10 < 2$. So if $\gamma_n = 0.1$ how can we conclude that $\frac{d_n}{1+d_n} < \epsilon$. Must we no atleast say $\frac{d_n}{1+d_n} < \frac{\epsilon}{\gamma_n}$?

Comment: Neither did I mean nor did I do it.I said if for two sequences $a_n,b_n$ you have $|a_nb_n|<\epsilon \forall \epsilon >0$ and $|a_n|\le M$ ,thencan't you conclude that $|b_n|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can prove that $\{ x^k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X $ is Cauchy sequence iff $\{ x^k_n\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X_n$ is Cauchy sequence for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.